# Django/Python cannot import module from script, but can import from IDE

Tags: python, django

I am running a script via a celery task and for some reason I cannot import one of my app models. If I try to import the model from the IDE it imports OK.

I am setting up my environment like this:

```
#! /tools/envs/networktools/networktools/bin/ipython
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/tools/envs/networktools/nettools/')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'nettools.settings')
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

from siteinfo.models import SiteCode, Subnets
from pingsweep.models import RunTime, HostStatus << this causes the following error
```

Error when running via script

```
(networktools) NetworkTools> tail logs/celery-worker.log
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tools/envs/networktools/nettools/scripts/python/pingsweep/pingsweep_db.py in <module>()
      8
      9 from siteinfo.models import SiteCode, Subnets
---> 10 from pingsweep.models import RunTime, HostStatus
     11
     12 from operator import itemgetter

ImportError: No module named 'pingsweep.models'; 'pingsweep' is not a package
```

If I run via the IDE I can import the package

```
In [1]: #! /tools/envs/networktools/networktools/bin/ipython

In [2]: import os

In [3]: import sys

In [4]: sys.path.append('/tools/envs/networktools/nettools/')

In [5]: os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'nettools.settings')
Out[5]: 'nettools.settings'

In [6]: from django.conf import settings

In [7]: from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

In [8]: from siteinfo.models import SiteCode, Subnets

In [9]: from pingsweep.models import RunTime, HostStatus

In [10]:
```

After some searching around my suspicion is a name space issue, but I cannot find a conflict. Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: Have you got an `__init__.py` file in your `pingsweep` directory? Also, if you're using Django 1.8 (and maybe 1.7) you'll need to call `django.setup()` for everything to be loaded correctly.

Comment: I have an     __init__.py, ill try     django.setup() and see how that goes, also using Django 1.8

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Unfortunately no dice, same error. FYI, have not had to use django.setup() before and I have numerous scripts running with the same setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems you've got your modules arranged in a weird way, so you're going to need to add more paths into your sys.paths.

```
sys.path.append('/tools/envs/networktools/nettools/scripts/python/')
```

It all depends which directory you're starting the interpreter from. I'm assuming you're opening the interpreter from your IDE from the python directory I'm adding to `sys.path` above, which will put the `pingsweep` module directly on your path.

Your script is starting from `nettools` directory though. If you wanted to access `pingsweep` from there, you'd need to say:

```
from scripts.python.pingsweep import .. # dont do this
```

But you'd also need to ensure there was a `__init__.py` file in the `scripts` and `python` directories. That's probably *not* what you want to do though.

Comment: Thanks Josh for the reply's. This module `from siteinfo.models import SiteCode, Subnets` is in the same structure level as `from pingsweep.models import RunTime, HostStatus`. Ill try altering the path and see how that goes

Comment: Looks like it was indeed a namespace issue. The script was in a folder named `pingsweep` and there was also another script named `pingsweep.py`. DUH. Thanks for the help @Josh Smeaton